# Restricting just a section of the page from editing

Tags: security, placeholders

On one of my templates I need to restrict the write/rename and deletion of a component that gets added by default on the items for a specific role to a placeholder only. I cannot restrict the user from adding the same component on other sections of the page, just on the header placeholder.

I have tried restricting permissions on the placeholder settings and I have confirmed on access viewer that the role has read only permissions but for some reason I can still edit it using experience editor.
I'm looking for ideas here, ideally that does not require customizations code wise.

Comment: Have you tried restricting the inheritance for the specific user or role?
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_inheritance_access_right#_Deny_an_account

Comment: retricting on which item you mean? Placeholder settings?

Comment: do you have your WebEdit.PlaceholdersEditableWithoutSettings set to "false" ? If yes, try to set it true and see if that works..

Answer (score 1):

You should set deny Write / Create / Delete permissions on the standard values of the component itself. If it's added via a branch template, and you specifically want it restricted only in this situation, you can set the permissions on the component in the branch.

Side note: When using the access viewer, I'd recommend checking access for a user, not a role. Users can typically have more than 1 role that could affect access.

Comment: Thanks Ben but I don't think that this would work in this case. 
The user should be able to edit, rename and delete on any placeholder except for one.

Comment: I know you mentioned you'd ideally not like to customize code, but to limit the placeholder security to one spot in particular, I think you'd either need to create a specific placeholder for that one place that's locked down, or add a custom processor to the `getPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar where certain users should not be allowed to add datasources to certain types of pages. We had a folder for every page that would contain its datasources. What we ended up doing was creating a second datasource folder type, inherited from the original, and then changed it to restrict create for the specific roles we needed to. It's a bummer that we needed a second template type that was basically just a to have different security defaults. It can be argued that a better solution would be to do this at the branch template level with the initial template type just being edited instead of being its own type. You might be able to do something similar where the items that need to be restricted are a different item type in order to have different security settings for every instance.